# Dynamic coding error main(teste.java:38) Java

Tags: java, recursion, error-handling, dynamic-programming

I am trying to make a function that receives three parameters int target, int nums[], int numbersQuantity. It returns true or false, true if you can achieve target = 0 using only the numbers in the array and only x (numbersQuantity) times...
Example: sum(13, {1,5,8,11}, 1) -> false because you can only use one number (numbersQuantity = 1), and there is no 13 on the array.

sum(13, {1,5,8,11},2) -> true because 5 +8 (two numbers) = 13

sum(15, {1,5,8,11}, 3) ->  true because you can use 3 numbers 5 +5 +5 = 15 (target)

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

        at teste.main(teste.java:38)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class teste {
    ArrayList<Integer> memoInt;
    List<Boolean> memoBoolean[];
    int index;
    teste() {
        this.memoInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.memoBoolean = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        this.index = 0;
    }
    public boolean sum(int target, int nums[], int numbersQuantity) {
        if(numbersQuantity <= 0) { return target == 0;}
        if(target < 0) { return false;}

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int rest = target - nums[i];

            for(int j = 0; j <index; j++) {
                if(memoInt.get(j) == rest ) {
                    return memoBoolean.get(j);
                }
            }
           if(sum(rest, nums, numbersQuantity-1)) {
               memoInt.add(rest);
               memoBoolean.add(true);
               index++;
               return true;
           }
           memoInt.add(rest);
           memoBoolean.add(false);
           index++;

        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int target = 13;
        int nums[] = {1,5,8,11};
        int numbersQuantity = 1;
        teste t = new teste();
        while(!t.sum(target, nums, numbersQuantity)) {
            numbersQuantity++;
        }
        System.out.println(numbersQuantity);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to `import java.util.List;`?

Comment: Dammm... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: not sure why you don't have a sane error - it should say something about not knowing what List is ..